# Good style when passing many variables to Jinja render_template()?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am rendering a Jinja template where I have to pass many variables. I can use this syntax when there are a few variables:

```
return render_template('page.html', var1 = foo, var2 = bar, var3 = baz)
```

but this quickly becomes unwieldy when passing, say 15 variables. Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps passing in a list or dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can pass any dict instead of the keyword arguments for any python function.

use this syntax:

```
d = {
   'var1': foo,
   'var2': bar,
   'var3': baz,
}

return render_template('page.html', **d)
```